# VueJS v-model with v-for

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My requirement is something like this.

1. I am rendering a question paper from an object using v-for.
2. Once the user **select an answer for a question**, the **question number (index) has to be v-model** with that answer. How can I achieve this? this is my code.

```js
<template lang="html">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="" v-for="(question,index) in questions">
      <h1>Question {{index}}</h1>
      <p>{{question.question}}</p>
      <input type="radio" name="index" value="1">{{question.answer1}}<br>
      <input type="radio" name="index" value="2">{{question.answer2}}<br>
      <input type="radio" name="index" value="3">{{question.answer3}}

    </div>
    <hr>
    <button type="button" name="button" class="btn">Save and Submit</button>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data(){
    return{
      questions:[
        {question:"what is the capital of france?",answer1:"paris",answer2:"normandy",answer3:"rome"},
        {question:"what is the capital of france?",answer1:"paris",answer2:"normandy",answer3:"rome"},
        {question:"what is the capital of france?",answer1:"paris",answer2:"normandy",answer3:"rome"}]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<template lang="html">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="" v-for="(question,index) in questions">
      <h1>Question {{index}}</h1>
      <p>{{question.question}}</p>
      <input type="radio" :name="index" :value="question.answer1" @click="pushAnswers(index, 1)">{{question.answer1}}<br>
      <input type="radio" :name="index" :value="question.answer2" @click="pushAnswers(index, 2)">{{question.answer2}}<br>
      <input type="radio" :name="index" :value="question.answer3" @click="pushAnswers(index, 3)">{{question.answer3}}
    </div>
    <hr>
    <button type="button" name="button" class="btn">Save and Submit</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

**Method**

```
pushAnswers(questionIndex,answer) {
  this.answerSet[questionIndex] = answer;
  console.log(this.answerSet);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a `v-model` to in the radioboxes.

A simple way to do that is to create a `selectedAnswer` property in each `question` and bind `v-model` to it, like:

```html
<input type="radio" value="1" v-model="question.selectedAnswer">{{question.answer1}}<br>
```

Notice also that I removed the `name`. You were using the same `name` attributes to **all** checkboxes, and HTML will only allow one selected radio per group (per `name`)

To get **an array of selected answers**, you could simply create a computed property that maps the selected answers into an array. In the example below, the `this.answers` computed property is available with the answers.

Full demo below.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      questions: [{
          question: "what is the capital of france?",
          answer1: "paris",
          answer2: "normandy",
          answer3: "rome",
          selectedAnswer: null
        },
        {
          question: "what is the capital of france?",
          answer1: "paris",
          answer2: "normandy",
          answer3: "rome",
          selectedAnswer: null
        },
        {
          question: "what is the capital of france?",
          answer1: "paris",
          answer2: "normandy",
          answer3: "rome",
          selectedAnswer: null
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    answers() {
      return this.questions.map(q => q.selectedAnswer);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  Answers: {{ answers }}
  <div class="container">
    <div class="" v-for="(question,index) in questions">
      <h1>Question {{index}}</h1>
      <p>{{question.question}} | selected: {{question.selectedAnswer || 'none'}}</p>
      <input type="radio" value="1" v-model="question.selectedAnswer">{{question.answer1}}<br>
      <input type="radio" value="2" v-model="question.selectedAnswer">{{question.answer2}}<br>
      <input type="radio" value="3" v-model="question.selectedAnswer">{{question.answer3}}
    </div>
    
    <hr>
    <button type="button" name="button" class="btn">Save and Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This would not work. Where are you assigning the variable in the data for `question.selectedAnswer`? The data present as an array.

Comment: In the `v-model`.

Comment: Add a `<p>{{question.question}} | selected {{ question.selectedAnswer }}</p>` to see how it changes. I did test it before posting :D

Comment: You cannot access something directly with `question.selectedAnswer` when it is `questions[index].selectedAnswer`

Comment: There's a `v-for` there. `question` is the local variable of the `v-for`. It is not `questionS.selectedAnswer` it is `question.selectedAnswer`.

Comment: This code works. =) But how can I send these values in an object in the save and submit button?

Comment: I want to bind that value with index and send to the backend

Comment: To get an array, the simplest way is to create a computed. See the `answers` computed property there. You can use it anywhere in the code via `this.answers`.

Comment: I have updated the question with the computed properties, have a look.

Comment: @RuChernChong So.. what do you think? Do you see a problem? This is an honest question.

Comment: I could not understand your question initially until this answer is posted.

Comment: Thanks both of you guys for your help. I highly appreciate your support. I think v-model not be the solution with your answers and comments I write a code which works for the requirement. I attach that code as an answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

I feel `v-model` might not be the right solution in this case. Here is what I suggest you to do.

```
<template lang="html">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="" v-for="(question,index) in questions">
      <h1>Question {{index}}</h1>
      <p>{{question.question}}</p>
      <input type="radio" :name="index" :value="question.answer1" @click="answerSelect(index, question.answer1)">{{question.answer1}}<br>
      <input type="radio" :name="index" :value="question.answer2" @click="answerSelect(index, question.answer2)">{{question.answer2}}<br>
      <input type="radio" :name="index" :value="question.answer3" @click="answerSelect(index, question.answer3)">{{question.answer3}}

    </div>
    <hr>
    <button type="button" name="button" class="btn">Save and Submit</button>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      questions: [
        {
          question: "what is the capital of france?",
          answer1: "paris",
          answer2: "normandy",
          answer3: "rome"
        },
        {
          question: "what is the capital of france?",
          answer1: "paris",
          answer2: "normandy",
          answer3: "rome"
        },
        {
          question: "what is the capital of france?",
          answer1: "paris",
          answer2: "normandy",
          answer3: "rome"
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    answerSelect(questionIndex, answer) {
      const questions = [
        ...this.questions.slice(0, questionIndex),
        { ...this.questions[questionIndex], solution: answer },
        ...this.questions.slice(questionIndex + 1, this.questions.length)
      ];

      this.questions = questions;
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Here is a link to the code sandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/o5r2xqypo9

Comment: Yes you're correct. I follow you're method and change it further. Thanks a lot for your support! =) I attached my code as an answer as well.